# Install issues for Tabris 0.10.0 Demos

Tags: android, adt, tabris

I need some help getting the exact steps to download, install and run the Tabris 0.10.0 demos into Eclipse and Android ADT...

My starting point is with a working Eclipse Android ADT, where the helloworld example works ok on the Android emulator and also on an external Android device connected by USB.

> download "Tabris-0.10.0-SDK.zip" and unpack somewhere (I'm on Win 7 64bit if it makes any difference)
>
> Import existing projects from SDK's "android\tabris-android-0.10.0.zip". All good, successful and I can Run this as Tabris application on Android successfully.

Next I'd like to get the Tabris demos working locally rather than just running an app that points to the EclipseSource web resources, for which I assume I need the Tabris server, so...

> download "tabris-0.10.0.zip" from github and import into my workspace, which gives me projects com.eclipsesource.tabris/tabris.build/tabris.feature/tabris.repository/tabris.target/target.test

Import is ok, but there are errors shown in projects 'com.eclipsesource.tabris' and 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.test' such as 'org.junit cannot be resolved' and 'org.mockito cannot be resolved'.

> I assume this is because I need to set the Tabris Target to be the current Target Platform, so from 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.target' just imported I open 'tabris.target' and hit 'Set as Target Platform'.

This quickly completes and clears the problem with 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.test', but a new error exists in '**com.eclipsesource.tabris**' which I see in the 'Problems' view: "**An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace.**".

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Assuming we can overcome the above, I then would continue:

> import the Tabris demo projects which I downloaded from github called "tabris-demos-0.10.0.zip". I'm making an assumption that all these versions are compatible (?) trying to use everything labeled "0.10.0" where I can find one.

This zip contains projects 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.demos/demos.build/demos.feature/demos.product'. which all import ok, with no new errors.

However, at this point I cannot do anything with them as I'm still stuck with the previous problem in 'com.eclipsesource.tabris' - 'Problems' view: "An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace."

Ok, perhaps getting ahead of myself here, but assuming someone is able to help me get over this error, how do I then start the Tabris server-side? Which project should be run as a RAP application, or is it something slightly different to this?

Sorry if this is basic and obvious, but there appear to be quite a few components to getting a local Tabris app running and I'm confused as to what part does what! All help appreciated!

Thanks, John

Comment: Ok, so I discovered that the Tabris server is started by running project 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.demos' as 'OSGi framework'... makes sense, and I then point my browser at 'http://myserver:9090/index.json' for a list of the entrypoints.

Comment: Additionally, if I run 'com.eclipsesource.tabris.launcher' as Android application in my connected device I can do the same thing and point the Tabris app at 'http://myserver:9090/index.json' which also works perfectly!

Comment: So, perhaps the real question here is whether the problem in 'com.eclipsesource.tabris' matters at all... the one giving "An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace."? Can I ignore this and carry on regardless? ...or should I be worried?

Comment: Instead of leaving comments, you can edit your question, and add all the information you think is useful for others to help you...

Answer (score 0):

The tabris team adds the api baseline so that it can track when features have been added to a release. You can set your api baseline in eclipse yourself or simply ignore that warning by setting the option under: "Preferences -> Plug-in-Development -> API Baselines" -> "Missing API baseline" (at the bottom).